# null is not an object evaluating this.state.<name>

Tags: json, react-native, axios

The problem might be common but I am asking because I couldn't fix it. I am getting "*null is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.albums')*" at line 22

And also I am a bit not clear about the type of data that was returned after the call and how to handle it. Please, can someone help me in explaining this? I am in the learning phase. when I am directly alert the response.data I'm getting [object][object] I have to do JSON stringify to see the data. Why should we do this?

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import {Text} from 'react-native';
   import axios from 'axios';

   export default class AlbumList extends Component{
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        state = { albums : []};
        }

   componentWillMount(){
    console.log('in componentWillMount');
    //debugger;
    //alert("first"+this.state);
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({albums : response.data});
        //alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.albums));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
    });
}

renderAlbums(){
    return this.state.albums.map( album => <Text>{album.title}</Text>); //line 22
}

 componentDidMount() {
console.log('I was triggered during componentDidMount')
 }

render(){
    return(
        <Text>{this.renderAlbums()}</Text>
        //<Text>Hiii</Text>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `this` in your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { albums : []};
}
```

As for the alert, you can't alert an object it has to be a string. So alerting a `JSON` object is just `[object object]`. If you use `JSON.stringify` it converts the object to a string that can be used for the alert. In your `console` you can log objects fine, and their structure is more readable. I would stick to `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: Thanks!! Solved.
I got you about JSON and can you also please explain the story behind "this" we are using in the entire component building.

Comment: been searching for hours and you just saved my life!

Comment: hello i m having TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.tags.map') issue because my tags is empty first time any solution